# Get commodity index futures price on bloomberg api

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I need to get open, high, low, close, volume data from bloomberg api for commodities like CL1, S 1, C1...

Right now, I am doing

```
from xbbg import blp
blp.bdib(ticker="CL1 COMB Comdty", dt="2021-06-01", exch="CME")
```

which works for CL1, but it doesn't work when I try anything else. E.g. running

```
blp.bdib(ticker="S 1 COMB Comdty", dt="2021-06-01", exch="CME")
```

give me a KeyError: 'Cannot find exchange info for S1 COMB Comdty'

Any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xbbg uses an 'exchange' purely as a method for working out the timezone and trading hours for calls to the underlying Bloomberg API (as the API only takes a start and end UTC date/time).

The reason that "CL1" works and "S 1" doesn't is that the former ticker is listed in the default xbbg *assets.yml* file. This file provides a lookup of common tickers to identify their trading hours / TZ. The 'exchanges' are listed in *exch.yml*.

The parameter name to use for tickers that are not in *assets.yml* to specify CME is 'ref':

```
df = blp.bdib(ticker="S 1 COMB Comdty", dt="2021-06-01", ref="CME")
print(df.tail())
```

which gives:

```
                          S 1 COMB Comdty           ...                    
                                     open     high  ... num_trds      value
2021-06-01 14:15:00-04:00         1548.75  1550.00  ...      105  365683.75
2021-06-01 14:16:00-04:00         1549.75  1550.00  ...       45  161172.75
2021-06-01 14:17:00-04:00         1549.50  1549.50  ...       29  139409.25
2021-06-01 14:18:00-04:00         1548.50  1549.00  ...       24  168826.25
2021-06-01 14:19:00-04:00         1548.25  1548.75  ...       43  247673.00
```

Alternatively you could add an entry to the *assets.yml* file (  on the path *\Lib\site-packages\xbbg\markets\assets.yml* ):

```
Comdty:
  ...
  - tickers: [S]
    exch: CME
    freq: M
    is_fut: True
  ...
```

And then you can just call:

```
df = blp.bdib(ticker="S 1 COMB Comdty", dt="2021-06-01")
```

The exch.yml entry for CME is:

```
CME:
  tz: America/New_York
  allday: [1800, 1700]
  day: [800, 1700]
```

Comment: I tried your method and it works perfectly, but the data I can pull only goes back to  2020-12-16. How do I get data further back?

Comment: @JoeChan  From the API guide (https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf): "Bloomberg maintains a tick-by-tick history going back 140 business days for all securities where streaming data is 
available." So basically, you can only go back 6 months or so from today.